# Is there any reason why I need to use <form with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

My current code looks like this:

```
   <form name="home.forms.modal">
       ...
       <input ng-model="home.modal.data.text"></input>
       <input ng-class="{error: home.forms.modal.name.$error}"
              ng-model="home.modal.data.name"
              name="name"
              ng-minlength="5"
              ng-required="true" />
       ...
   </form>
   <button ng-disabled="home.forms.modal.$invalid"
           ng-click="home.modalSubmit(home.modal.data)">Submit</button>
```

I noticed there have been recent changes with messages for forms. What I would like to know is there anything at all in AngularJS that requires me to use the form element. If so then how could I change the above code so it would work with just a DIV ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ng-form attribute on any element

```
<div ng-form  name="home.forms.modal">
   ...
   <input ng-model="home.modal.data.text"></input>
    ...
 </div>
  <button ng-click="home.modalSubmit(home.modal.data)">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I updated my question just a bit. With the additional things such as validation and a check for $invalid does your answer still apply ?

Comment: Yes, it does.  The beauty of this route is that you can embed elements with the ng-form attribute within each other (whereas browsers do not allow for the embedding of form elements within another form element).

Comment: Check out the information at this link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form for more information

Answer (score 1):

validation on the client is way to hell, you should get the validation errors by server in .error callback of $http , and show them to client.

You may need to use forms with such directives, like ui-mask, to get the right value.

Answer (score 1):

Using a form tag is syntactically correct, and some browsers (IE) do not display things correctly when you try to put form elements (input/button/textarea) into a page without them being surrounded by form tags.